# NullPointerException when powermockito testing method invocation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I'm new to unit testing with powermockito and currently i'm trying to test a method that calls `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`. I've tried to run the test but it failed and showed `NullPointerException` at the line where an object invoke a method that i suppose my object here is not null. Here is my code, i've summarized the part that may cause the problem.

**DailyReminderTest.java**

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DailyReminder.class)
public class DailyReminderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DailyReminder dailyReminder;

    @Mock
    User user;

    @Mock
    Timer mockTimer;

    @Mock
    TimerTask mockTask;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        TimerTask task = new MyTask(user);
        mockTask = mock(task.getClass());

        dailyReminder = new DailyReminder() {
            @Override
            public Timer createTimer() {
                return mockTimer;
            }

            @Override
            public TimerTask createTask() {
                return mockTask;
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    void testRemind() throws Exception {
        dailyReminder.remind();  // here is the line where NullPointerException occured
        verify(mockTimer).scheduleAtFixedRate(eq(mockTask), any(Date.class), anyLong());
    }
}
```

**DailyReminder.java**

```java
public class DailyReminder {

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask task;
    private User user;
    private Date dateStart;
    private final Duration fixedDuration = Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    
    // some constructor here...
    
    public void remind() {
        timer = createTimer();
        task = createTask();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, dateStart, fixedDuration.toMillis());
    }

    public Timer createTimer() {
        return new Timer();
    }

    public TimerTask createTask() {
        return new MyTask(user);
    }
}
```

I also have tried `assertNull(dailyReminder)` however the stack trace shows

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <null> but was: <Daily Reminder>
```

which is weird that dailyReminder there wasn't null. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: can you also share what versions of junit and powermock are you using?

Comment: `mockTimer` is null.

Comment: @deepakchethan im using powermock 2.0.0-beta.5 and junit4. I dont exactly know the junit release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `PowerMockRunner`, you have to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()` in order to initialise the mocks that are created using the annotations. Currently `mockTimer` is null giving you NPE. You can either initialise it in `beforeEach` like you are doing for other mocks or call `initMocks()` to fix this.

Comment: well that was quite a silly error hahaha. Thanks a lot tho!